# using boost program_options and auto completion

Tags: c++, bash, boost, autocomplete

I'm having a command line application using boost::program_options.

It already notifies the user, via exception handling of program_options, about such things like ambiguous parameters:

```
Error occured when parsing arguments: option '--foo' is ambiguous and 
matches 'foo_do', and 'foo_bar'
```

If a substring of a parameter is not ambiguous, it also uses it to identify the matching command (i.e., if I enter "foo_b", it will complete to "foo_bar").

Is there any simple way to exploit this already available knowledge for simple command line auto completion?

Are there any experiences on how to pass your static information about command line parameters to bash's auto completion, as well as to program_options?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can exploit it, but you'll have to write it yourself. It's probably easier to rely on the "standard" mechanisms usually employed in auto-completion scripts.

I think bash_completion comes with enough smart that it will DoTheRightThing given a plain list of long option names.

Comment: thanks, that was already a useful pointer - I was not familiar how auto completion usually works at all, your answer now pushes me more in the direction of providing a list of option names for bash-completion.